# How to change max height of item in List view

Tags: android, listview, height, max

I have a stupid problem but I'm not able to solve it. I have a listView with custom layout of items (nothing complicated - three TextViews) and I need to change reduce the height of items in list. I tried to set android:layout_height="70px" in item_layout.xml but it seems that this value do not have any affect on final height.

Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Thanks a lot!

In main.xml

```
<ListView
 android:id="@+id/wf8_card_list"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="160px" 
 android:layout_marginLeft="-10px"
 android:layout_marginRight="-10px"
 android:layout_weight="0.5"
 android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
 android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
 android:cacheColorHint = "#00000000"
 android:listSelector="@drawable/transaction_list_bacground"/>
```

In myActivity.java

```
> ListView lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.my%list);
>       lv1.setAdapter(new PaymentAdapter(this,R.layout.list_layout , my_array_list));
```

In list_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="70px">
 ...
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on your Item. You should make the item expandable whenever required. You could also probably handle this in the getView method of your adapter.